# Calling transfer function using interface for ERC20

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to send ERC20 tokens from a contract to an account .
This is the code that I have

```
IERC20 testToken = IERC20(tokenAddress);
testToken.transfer(accountAddress,amount);
```

The function to intitate the trasfer should ideally be called by someone else, lets call him "C"
So

```
msg.sender != accountAddress
```

- Is there a way I can make the msg.sender for the transfer function to
  be the contract itself instead of "C" ?
- Also this function somehow works if I i call it from the account
  address ,i.e when msg.sender == accountAddress . How does that happen
  ,in this case the from and to fields should both be the same ,and no
  change in balance should happen ?

Comment: As written, your contract will transfer _its own_ testToken to `accountAddress`, no matter who calls it.  That sounds like what you want : "I am trying to send ERC20 tokens from a contract to an account". no ?

Comment: Yeah That is what I want , but if its a third person calling this smart contract , the transfer does not happen .

Comment: So you wanna transfer the token from smart contract -> msg.sender?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the `transferFrom` function and not `transfer`. The transfer function automatically uses the `msg.sender` as a parameter. You will also have to have that address have allowance of the tokens to transfer. The  `approve` method takes care of this. Assuming that is all set, here is the code.

```js
 IERC20 tcontract = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    require(tcontract.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, amount), "Don't have enough balance");
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Ideally i would not want to use transferfrom , as its a contract

Comment: Cant I do the same thing using just transfer ?

Comment: If you don't use this transferFrom in your contract then where are using this?

Comment: And as it's one of the core functions of ERC20 so feel free to use this